# Why does the careers site not list anyone in New Zealand?

Tags: support, jobs

I've set my profile to actively looking. But I seem to be invisible. I feel very lonely over here :-)

Edit: Got my invite - thanks.

Comment: `I feel very long over here.` Bah...bragger.

Comment: hahahaha just edit it lol

Comment: I see ~350 candidates when I search for "New Zealand" on the [candidate search page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/candidate-search), including you.  Where were you seeing zero?

Comment: On the map where the the numbers are overlayed